# Panda Dataframe Find rows which does not have equivalent value in the DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

DataFrame:

```
    column1     column2
0   some_data   string1
1   some_data   string1
2   some_data   string2
3   some_data   string3
4   some_data   string2
5   some_data   string4
5   some_data   string4
...
20k+ rows in total
```

Explanation:
For most rows, column2 data appear in pairs. I want to find out rows that do not have paired data (e.g. string3)

Expected Output:

```
   column1    column2
0   some_data  string3
```

Any solutions to find out such rows? thanks!

Comment: In complement to @jezrael answer I added an alternative to get paired data (*i.e.*, if an even number of rows, it keeps only the first paired ones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible simplify problem for found all rows without dupes by `column2` use:

```
df1 = df[~df['column2'].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

If need test counts and filter all rows without pairs (2):

```
df2 = df[df.groupby('column2')['column2'].transform('size').ne(2)]
```

Also if need test all pairs, it means `2, 4, 6, 8`... use:

```
df3 = df[df.groupby('column2')['column2'].transform('size') % 2 == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to take only a pair number of rows, working as a pipeline:

```
(df.groupby('column2', as_index=False)
   .apply(lambda d: d.iloc[:2*(len(d)//2)]) # transform any odd to previous even
   .droplevel(0)
)
```

output:

```
     column1  column2
0  some_data  string1
1  some_data  string1
2  some_data  string2
4  some_data  string2
5  some_data  string4
5  some_data  string4
```